# @RelationshipEntity not hydrated

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

The same code, executed with the new snapshot version of spring-data-neo4j (4.2.0.BUILD-20170123.104601-200) doesn't return the existent relationship

```
@Query("MATCH (a:User) - [r:FRIEND_WITH] -> (b:Person) RETURN r, a, b")
FriendshipEntity loadFriendship(...);

@RelationshipEntity(type="FRIEND_WITH")
public class FriendshipEntity {
    @GraphId   private Long relationshipId;
    @StartNode private User user;
    @EndNode   private Person person;
}
```

The same code executed with the previous version (4.2.0.BUILD-20161223.121144-184) works well

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. Please open up a bug report here: jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH

Comment: In the new release I noticed that the reference to the relationship entity in either source or target node is needed to work. Before it is not required, is it correct?